# Azure data factory pipeline: conditional checking on variable activity

Tags: azure, rest, api, azure-data-factory

I have a web activity to call a REST API and save it output into a table. But one of its value will not available always. So we need to do a conditional checking while setting its output into a variable activity.
you can see how we have done that in the variable activity.

This is the rest APIs output.

```
{
 "value": {
     "id": "464a115fd3cb",
     "runId": "464a115fd3cb",
     "parameters": {},
     "invokedBy": {
         "id": "99448303872CU28",
         "name": "TRIGGER_TIMESHEET_API",
         "invokedByType": "ScheduleTrigger"
     },
     "isLatest": true
 },
 "continuationToken": "+RID:~sj5QALRCCB4w5hYAAAAADQ",
 "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
     "Pragma": "no-cache"

 }
```

}

Here "continuationToken" will not be a part of all the API responses. So if this value is available in the API response, we need to set that in the variable activity.
In the attached screenshot, you can see that we are setting the variable. But if that key is not available in the API response, it will throw an error. 
So we are looking for a solution to check whether that key is existing in the JSON output.
[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: hi,any updates here?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes. It is working. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you almost get your goal already,please use Set Variable Activity and If-Condition Activity:

[image]

Set Variable Activity:

[image]

If-Condition Activity to judge the name is empty or not:

[image]

Then you could configure the True Activity and False Activity:

[image]